# Find a value in webpage source code (Fortran)

Tags: fortran

how can i extract numerical data from a webpage source code that is embedded in a text file using fortran? (e.g https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE:KO) My aim is to retrieve the stock price through the source code. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Right-click -> Inspect Source` (or `Inspect Element`, depends on the web browser) shows (with a simple search) that the data is presented as a Flash animation and is not stored in the HTML.

Comment: You may be interested in some of the APIs given by the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to do that in Fortran? Fortran is not very well suited for string manipulation (in my opinion)!

I would recommend to get and process the HTML in another language (e.g. Python), and write in the data in a structured way that Fortran can directly `read`. You could call that script / program from Fortran using the statement

```
call system('command')
```

Comment: The data isn't stored in the HTML, so this (good) idea is useless.

Comment: Actually Fortran has couple useful string processing procedures which many do not emloy enough. `scan`, `index`, `verify`, internal i/o...

Comment: That's true, but still - it's no fun doing so.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Let me rephrase my statement: You can do it in Fortran (and I did it in the past as well), but it is not easy and time-consuming. I found it easier to read in pre-processed data.